# Stream response parts with Axios

Tags: json, typescript, axios

I am trying to use Axios to receive a stream from the OpenAI API using a parameter (stream = true) that returns multiple responses in JSON pieces.

When I run my request in Postman, I can read the responses as individual JSON objects that I can use:

[image]

However, attempting the same request in axios, I'm not able to get to the parsed json.

My function returns the request:

```
return axios
        .post('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', {
            model: "gpt-4",
            messages: messages,
            stream: true,
        }, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + secretKey,
                'accept': 'application/json',
                'content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            responseType: 'stream',
        })
```

and my test file simply attempts to get the Buffer chunks, and parse them into Json without success:

```
const stream = await streamChatGPTResponseForOpenChat([], 'What is science?', null)

stream.data.on('data', (data: Buffer) => {
                try {
                    const str = data.toString('utf8'); //This reads "data: {'foo': 'bar', ... }

                    //I've tried this to parse manually, but it fails with some of the chunks:

                    // console.log(str);
                    // const startIndex = str.indexOf('{');
                    // const endIndex = str.lastIndexOf('}') + 1;

                    // This is my current attempt. But also fails with about 30% of chunks and ALWAYS fails with the first chunk.
                    const json = JSON.parse(str.replace('data: ', ''));

                    const msg = json.choices[0].delta.content;
                    console.log(msg);

                    if (msg.includes('\n')) {
                        console.log('-----');

                        messages.push(currentMessage);
                        currentMessage = '';
                    }

                currentMessage = currentMessage.concat(msg);

                expect(data).to.be.a.string;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error: ' + error);
                console.log(data.toString());
                reject(error);
            }
        });

        stream.data.on('end', () => {
            console.log('DONE');
            resolve('done');
        });
```

Error #1, always on the first chunk: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 198" -> Interestingly, this points to the axios request file, not to the implementation (test) file.

Error #2, randomly: "error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 195" -> This is caught in the on('data' function, but the json its trying to parse seems correct.

I assume I'm converting buffer to data wrongly. Is there anything that jumps to mind in my implementation that is not correct?

Thanks!